# Jolt: Merge arrays

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to create a transform for the input below:

```json
{
  "Empresa": "13530",
  "Rotas": {
    "Codigo": "4740523719166",
    "Entregas": [
      {
        "Cliente": {
          "Codigo": "4083082796",
          "Nome": "EMPRESA TESTE",
          "Tipo": 1
        },
        "Pedidos": [
          {
            "Codigo": "5327053",
            "NotasFiscais": [
              {
                "Numero": "216550",
                "TipoOperacao": "SAIDA",
                "NotaFiscalItens": [
                  {
                    "Produto": {
                      "Codigo": "23702",
                      "Nome": "PRODUTO TESTE 2"
                    },
                    "Quantidade": "5.0000",
                    "TipoProduto": {
                      "Descricao": "Diversos",
                      "Codigo": "1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Cliente": {
          "Codigo": "4083082796",
          "Nome": "EMPRESA TESTE",
          "Tipo": 1
        },
        "Pedidos": [
          {
            "Codigo": "5327054",
            "NotasFiscais": [
              {
                "Numero": "216558",
                "TipoOperacao": "SAIDA",
                "NotaFiscalItens": [
                  {
                    "Produto": {
                      "Codigo": "2694",
                      "Nome": "PRODUTO TESTE02"
                    },
                    "Quantidade": "6.0000",
                    "TipoProduto": {
                      "Descricao": "Diversos",
                      "Codigo": "1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Cliente": {
          "Codigo": "5589685412",
          "Nome": "EMPRESA TESTE02",
          "Tipo": 1
        },
        "Pedidos": [
          {
            "Codigo": "5327060",
            "NotasFiscais": [
              {
                "Numero": "316270",
                "TipoOperacao": "SAIDA",
                "NotaFiscalItens": [
                  {
                    "Produto": {
                      "Codigo": "219",
                      "Nome": "PRODUTO EXEMPLO"
                    },
                    "Quantidade": "5.0000",
                    "TipoProduto": {
                      "Descricao": "Diversos",
                      "Codigo": "1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With the desired output of:

```json
{
  "Empresa": "13530",
  "Rotas": {
    "Codigo": "4740523719166",
    "Entregas": [
      {
        "Cliente": {
          "Codigo": "4083082796",
          "Nome": "EMPRESA TESTE",
          "Tipo": 1
        },
        "Pedidos": [
          {
            "Codigo": "5327053",
            "NotasFiscais": [
              {
                "Numero": "216550",
                "TipoOperacao": "SAIDA",
                "NotaFiscalItens": [
                  {
                    "Produto": {
                      "Codigo": "23702",
                      "Nome": "PRODUTO TESTE 2"
                    },
                    "Quantidade": "5.0000",
                    "TipoProduto": {
                      "Descricao": "Diversos",
                      "Codigo": "1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "Numero": "216558",
                "TipoOperacao": "SAIDA",
                "NotaFiscalItens": [
                  {
                    "Produto": {
                      "Codigo": "2694",
                      "Nome": "PRODUTO TESTE02"
                    },
                    "Quantidade": "6.0000",
                    "TipoProduto": {
                      "Descricao": "Diversos",
                      "Codigo": "1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Cliente": {
          "Codigo": "5589685412",
          "Nome": "EMPRESA TESTE02",
          "Tipo": 1
        },
        "Pedidos": [
          {
            "Codigo": "5327060",
            "NotasFiscais": [
              {
                "Numero": "316270",
                "TipoOperacao": "SAIDA",
                "NotaFiscalItens": [
                  {
                    "Produto": {
                      "Codigo": "219",
                      "Nome": "PRODUTO EXEMPLO"
                    },
                    "Quantidade": "5.0000",
                    "TipoProduto": {
                      "Descricao": "Diversos",
                      "Codigo": "1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not able to merge the information regarding the 'Cliente', as it is repeated in the two objects of the 'Entregas' array.  I need the merge to occur so that the information referring to 'Customer' appears only once. can anybody help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: sorry, it's not necessary, already adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Start evaluation by diving upto `NotasFiscais` by such a constructor below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Rotas": {
        "Entregas": {
          "*": {
            "Pedidos": {
              "*": {
                "NotasFiscais": {
                  "*": {
                    "@": "&4[&5].&2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and then develop it by adding proper **&** and **@** sign substitutions within that **shift** transformation, and then pick the first element of the list `Entregas` by using index value **0** in the last step such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "Rotas": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "Entregas": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.&2[&1].&",
            "Pedidos": {
              "*": {
                "Codigo": {
                  "@": "&6.&5[0].&3[&4].&1"
                },
                "NotasFiscais": {
                  "*": {
                    "@": "&7.&6[0].&4[&5].&2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "Rotas": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "Entregas": {
          "0": "&2.&1[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/
[image]

Comment: I understand, however if I have more than one different element within the `Entregas` list, there would be no way to reference it with a value index of 0. Would the structure have to change? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi @Maikon , can you edit the input and the desired output depending on your current need?

Comment: Hi, ok, only a moment.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan , i made the desired input and output change.